# When I integrate rtf template into my javaee Dynamic web Application,occur

Tags: jakarta-ee

This error is display in IE8 explorer.

**RTFTemplateServlet: Error processing RTF edition**
No bean named 'vmRTFTemplate' is definedorg.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'vmRTFTemplate' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:642)
    at net.sourceforge.rtf.helper.RTFTemplateBuilder.newRTFTemplate(RTFTemplateBuilder.java:85)
    at net.sourceforge.rtf.helper.RTFTemplateBuilder.newRTFTemplate(RTFTemplateBuilder.java:100)
    at net.sourceforge.rtf.web.servlet.AbstractRTFTemplateServlet.doRequest(AbstractRTFTemplateServlet.java:118)
    at net.sourceforge.rtf.web.servlet.AbstractRTFTemplateServlet.doGet(AbstractRTFTemplateServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your are not declare spring bean named  "vmRTFTemplate", check your spring config files.